# Text-to-speech model that trains on small training dataset

Tags: machine-learning, audio, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, huggingface

I am in need of a model that can train with a dataset comprising of a transcript and wav files for maximum 20 sentences.
I tried to train https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS on such a dataset and it did not train well at all. The inference was just noise rather than words.

I am looking into https://github.com/microsoft/SpeechT5/tree/main/SpeechLM#pre-trained-and-fine-tuned-models but it seems like the fine tuning dataset they use also has >100 hours of audio content.

What is the best model to research to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/p0p4k/pflowtts_pytorch
can be trained on few hours dataset

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35545205)